# Strapi - Validation Error 400 this must be a `object` type, but the final value was: `null`

Tags: postman, strapi

I am trying to post a json to my Strapi API, but I got this error `"this must be a` object`type, but the final value was:`null

My Json data is:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "cveID": "CVE-2021-27104",
            "vendorProject": "Accellion",
            "product": "FTA",
            "vulnerabilityName": "Accellion FTA OS Command Injection Vulnerability",
            "dateAdded": "2021-11-03",
            "shortDescription": "Accellion FTA 9_12_370 and earlier is affected by OS command execution via a crafted POST request to various admin endpoints.",
            "requiredAction": "Apply updates per vendor instructions.",
            "dueDate": "2021-11-17"
        },
        {
            "cveID": "CVE-2021-27102",
            "vendorProject": "Accellion",
            "product": "FTA",
            "vulnerabilityName": "Accellion FTA OS Command Injection Vulnerability",
            "dateAdded": "2021-11-03",
            "shortDescription": "Accellion FTA 9_12_411 and earlier is affected by OS command execution via a local web service call.",
            "requiredAction": "Apply updates per vendor instructions.",
            "dueDate": "2021-11-17"
        }]
}
```

The table schema is like in the pic
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are sending an array remove the [] and your post will work.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that in Python you need first to do your serialization and then fetch it in Strapi

```
    json_string = json.dumps(to_post)
    data = json.loads(json_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some messed up relational field. Error went away after i cleared and remade the relation.

Answer (score 0):

```js
{
    "data": {info: [
        {
            "cveID": "CVE-2021-27104",
            "vendorProject": "Accellion",
            "product": "FTA",
            "vulnerabilityName": "Accellion FTA OS Command Injection Vulnerability",
            "dateAdded": "2021-11-03",
            "shortDescription": "Accellion FTA 9_12_370 and earlier is affected by OS command execution via a crafted POST request to various admin endpoints.",
            "requiredAction": "Apply updates per vendor instructions.",
            "dueDate": "2021-11-17"
        },
        {
            "cveID": "CVE-2021-27102",
            "vendorProject": "Accellion",
            "product": "FTA",
            "vulnerabilityName": "Accellion FTA OS Command Injection Vulnerability",
            "dateAdded": "2021-11-03",
            "shortDescription": "Accellion FTA 9_12_411 and earlier is affected by OS command execution via a local web service call.",
            "requiredAction": "Apply updates per vendor instructions.",
            "dueDate": "2021-11-17"
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).